# Histogram with Frequency and Density axises simultaneously in R

Tags: r

I can combine both density and frequency plots like this

```
hist(ex, col="red", prob=TRUE)
lines(density(ex), col="red")
```

But is it possible to also have both axes on each side? Just an example:

[image: fake plot]

UPDATED: Solution that depends on the actual data:

```
#margin from right
par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 4) + 0.1)

hist(ex, col="red", prob=TRUE)
lines(density(ex), col="red")

# axis ticks
axis(4, at=seq(0,0.4,0.1)*50, labels=seq(0,0.4,0.1)*2500)
# axis label
mtext("Frequency", side=4, line=3)
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html .

Comment: A dynamic solution would be better but yours works too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re your comment: here is a quick go at a formula using **base R** - based on your code above - where you will not have to manually define the axes. The obvious difficulty is either the density or the frequency wont be pretty/round numbers (if you want them to both be round then the ticks will likely be at different places). I think it is more sensible to to have the density at defined intervals. Also this requires constant breaks.

For the plot i assign the density to the LHS axis but this will be easy enough to tweak.

```
histfreq <- function(X, lines=TRUE, ...) {

        par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 4) + 0.1)
        h <- hist(X, plot=FALSE)
        n.obs <- length(na.omit(X))
        d <- density(na.omit(X))
        h <- hist(X, prob=TRUE, yaxt="n",ylim = c(0,max(h$density,d$y)*1.1),...)

        # axis ticks and labels
        # y          
        axis(2, at = pretty(c(0,h$density)), 
            labels = formatC( pretty(c(0,h$density)), digits = 1, format = "f"))

        # 2nd y
        axis(4, at = pretty(c(0,h$density)), 
            labels = formatC(signif(pretty(c(0,h$density)) * n.obs * 
                 unique(diff(h$breaks)), digits = 2),  digits=0, format = "f"))

        mtext("Frequency" ,  side=4, line=3)

        if (lines) lines(d, ...)          
    }

# Call plot
histfreq(rnorm(57), col="red")
```